# Any function to extract key and value pair without a loop

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way of extracting key and value pair without a loop?

*Note:* There will always be **only one index** in the array.

Thanks

```
$array = array(81 => array(66 => 47272));

[81] => Array
(
    [66] => 47272
)
```

Comment: do you mean somethin like this: `echo $array[81][66];`?

Comment: And what's the expected result?

Comment: so do you want 81 in key variable and the array(66=>47272) in value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want [`each` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) and [`list` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($key, $value) = each($array);
```

Comment: Nice and tidy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract information from your array using the [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function and the [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function. `key()` returns the key of the current element (defaults to first element) and `current()` returns the value.

Neither `key()` or `current()` advance the array pointer.

```
$key = key($array); // = 81
$arr2 = current($array); // = array(66 => 47272)
$key2 = key($arr2); // = 66
$value = current($arr2); // = 47272
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php) to get the key.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$value = $array[$keys[0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key1 = array_keys($array)[0];
$keyReal = array_keys($array[$key1])[0];  // The key
$valueReal = $array[$key1][$keyReal];     // The value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$var1 = $array[81]; //Returns array(66 => 47272)
$var2 = $array[81][66]; //Returns 47272
```

Comment: I think he does not know the indices.